# Wordpress - getting rid of default post when creating pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When you first create a page in Wordpress it creates a default post with the title of that page along with comments and date created.  How do you get rid of it?  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I should add that none of these post show up under the posts section so it's not a case of deleting them there.

Comment: Where are you seeing these posts? Do they appear in the blog or in your database?

Comment: I'm seeing them in both, it seems when I create a page it creates an empty automatic post with the same title.  These posts do not show up in the posts section - so you can't delete them.  If you edit the title in the pages section and update the page with no title, the date created and the option to leave a comment are still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable comments in each post/page separately. Date you can disable with plugins such as Publish silently or Stealth publish.

Comment: Sorry must be the %$^&*& standard theme, but there's no option to even disable comments globally. let alone per post or page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  Used display:hidden in css to hide only the page title when posting.